# Rails 3 get Username by ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get the Username from an ID in Rails 3?
In my view I call <%= blog.user_id %> for the ID, but how do I get the Name there?

The Controller is a scaffold default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you define the association in your `Blog` model.

```
belongs_to :user
```

And then in your view your can use `<%= blog.user.name %>`

Comment: I've done that but i get an error:
undefined method `name' for "#<User:0x00000102b7a630>":User


The name is saved in username. When i change it to username the error is: 

undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Comment: In that case, I also suspect you have a blog instance without an associated user. To avoid the error you can use: `<%= blog.user.try(:username) %>`.

Comment: Great that worked for me! I forget to delete the old blog posts without the user id. After deleting them your first solution worked as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want to avoid long chains of dots like post.user.name. Try:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :name, :to => :user, :prefix => true
end
```

Then in your views you can call

```
@post.user_name
```

to get the users name. I thought I would throw this out there since its good habit I am trying to include in my code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<%= blog.user.name %>` and have defined

```
belongs_to :user
```

in your Blog model. You should work with `..._id` on the view-level.

Answer (score 0):

you should learn how to code in Rails, this is a very basic question.

Consider having a look at http://railsforzombies.org

It's a great online tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Try using <%= blog.user.try(:name) %>